# Why does the char* pointer value change when uncommenting the given line?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, argv

The address pointed by variable "string" is different to that of `argv[1]` when commenting and uncommenting line 9.

This behavior was observed in gcc from msys2 11.2.0 
However, the result was as expected when compiled from and run in Ubuntu gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Is this behavior undefined in C? What is causing the main problem here?

Test Case: compile and run by giving a argument
Eg: `gcc main.c -o main.exe <br> .\main.exe test.txt`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *string = argv[1];
    char string2[sizeof(string)];
    //strcpy(string2, argv[1]);     //line 9

    printf("%p\n", string);
    printf("%p\n", argv[1]);
    printf("sizeof(string) = %lu\n", sizeof(argv[1]));
    printf("length of string = %lu\n", strlen(string));
    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]:

Top --> Before Uncommenting line 9
Bottom --> After Uncommenting line 9

Comment: `sizeof(string)` is not the same as `strlen(string) + 1`, since `string` is a pointer and not an array.

Comment: [Why not upload code/text images in Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: To answer your question, yes, you invoke undefined behavior for any string at `argv[1]` longer than one-less the *size of a pointer* on your platform (leaving the last slot for a terminator).

Answer (score 2):

First,

Change this:

```
char string2[sizeof(string)];
```

To account for the possibility that string and argv[1] can be undefined or null. Further, you need this array to measure the length of the string, not the size of the pointer - which is always going to be 4 or 8.

```
char string2[(argc> 1) ? (strlen(string)+1) : 1];
```

The above will size `string2` to be long enough to hold a string copy from `string` (+1 for the null char) if it's not null to begin with. Otherwise, it's an array of length 0.

Second, your printf statements using `%lu` should explicitly push an unsigned long onto the call stack. It probably happens to be ok since only one arg is getting pushed per call. `printf` does't do great with null arguments either, so we can fix that up too.

Here's a cleaned up version of your code with some suggested corrections.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* string = argv[1];
    char string2[(argc> 1) ? (strlen(string)+1) : 0];

    if (argv[1])
    {
        strcpy(string2, argv[1]);
    }

    printf("%p\n", string);
    printf("%p\n", argv[1]);
    printf("sizeof(string) = %lu\n", (unsigned long)(sizeof(argv[1])));
    printf("length of string = %lu\n", (unsigned long)(string ? strlen(string) : 0));
    printf("%s\n", string?string:"<nil>");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has potential undefined behavior when you uncomment the call to `strcpy()`:

The definition `char string2[sizeof(string)];` defines an array of `char` with a length of 4 or 8 depending on the size of a pointer on your target.

You are probably copying a string that does not fit in the destination array, causing undefined behavior (such as overwriting other data as you observe).

If you want to make a copy of the string in `argv[1]`, you should first check that a command line argument was given and use:

```
 char string2[strlen(string) + 1];
```

The extra byte is required to store the null terminator copied by `strcpy()`.

Try this modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        char *string = argv[1];
        char string2[strlen(string) + 1];
        strcpy(string2, string);

        printf("%p\n", string);
        printf("%p\n", argv[1]);
        printf("sizeof(string) = %zu\n", sizeof(string));
        printf("strlen(string) = %zu\n", strlen(string));
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```